# Keras: Error with Training. Dimension is not what is expected

Tags: tensorflow, shapes, keras, training-data

I am developing a project where I am trying to finetune the last layer of a VGG-FACE model.
But everytime when I try to do the fitting stage I've got the same error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "freeze_2.py", line 258, in <module>
    model=entrenamos_modelo('vggface_weights_tensorflow.h5')  
  File "freeze_2.py", line 168, in entrenamos_modelo
    model2.fit(train_data,label, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, batch_size=64)

  File "/imatge/psereno/workspace/venv-tfg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1057, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)

  File "/imatge/psereno/workspace/venv-tfg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 984, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model input')

  File "/imatge/psereno/workspace/venv-tfg/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 111, in standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))

Exception: Error when checking model input: expected input_2 to have shape (None, 3, 224, 224) but got array with shape (1576, 4096, 1, 1)
```

Here is the code I am using:

```py
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Convolution2D, ZeroPadding2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.layers import merge
from keras.models import Merge
import cv2, numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

'''OJOOOOO: PARA QUE FUNCIONE BIEN:
nano ~/.keras/keras.json
{
"image_dim_ordering": "th",
"epsilon": 1e-07,
"floatx": "float32",
"backend": "tensorflow"
}
'''

def bottleneck():
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.)
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                                        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                        batch_size=32,
                                        class_mode=None,
                                        shuffle=False)

    pad1_1 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1), name='in_train')(img)
    conv1_1 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_1')(pad1_1)
    pad1_2 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1))(conv1_1)
    conv1_2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_2')(pad1_2)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv1_2)

    pad2_1 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(pool1)
    conv2_1 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_1')(pad2_1)
    pad2_2 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(conv2_1)
    conv2_2 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_2')(pad2_2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), trainable=False)(conv2_2)

    pad3_1 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(pool2)
    conv3_1 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_1')(pad3_1)
    pad3_2 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(conv3_1)
    conv3_2 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_2')(pad3_2)
    pad3_3 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(conv3_2)
    conv3_3 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_3')(pad3_3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), trainable=False)(conv3_3)

    pad4_1 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(pool3)
    conv4_1 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_1')(pad4_1)
    pad4_2 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(conv4_1)
    conv4_2 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_2')(pad4_2)
    pad4_3 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(conv4_2)
    conv4_3 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_3')(pad4_3)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv4_3)

    pad5_1 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(pool4)
    conv5_1 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_1')(pad5_1)
    pad5_2 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(conv5_1)
    conv5_2 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_2') (pad5_2)
    pad5_3 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1))(conv5_2)
    conv5_3 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_3')(pad5_3)
    pool5 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv5_3)
    fc6 = Convolution2D(4096, 7, 7, activation='relu', name='fc6')(pool5)
    fc6_drop = Dropout(0.5)(fc6)

    model = Model(input=img, output=fc6_drop)
    bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(generator, nb_train_samples)
    np.save(open('features.npy', 'w'), bottleneck_features_train)


def entrenamos_modelo(weights_path=None):

    train_data = np.load(open('features.npy'))
    print(train_data.shape)

    train_labels = np.array(
    [0] * (nb_train_samples / 8) + [1] * (nb_train_samples / 8) + [2] * (nb_train_samples / 8) + [3] * (
        nb_train_samples / 8) + [4] * (nb_train_samples / 8) + [5] * (nb_train_samples / 8) + [6] * (
        nb_train_samples / 8) + [7] * (nb_train_samples / 8))

    lbl1 = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ] * 197)
    lbl2 = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ] * 197)
    lbl3 = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ] * 197)
    lbl4 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], ] * 197)
    lbl5 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], ] * 197)
    lbl6 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], ] * 197)
    lbl7 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ] * 197)
    lbl8 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], ] * 197)
    label = np.concatenate([lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5, lbl6, lbl7, lbl8])
    '''train_labels --> loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
       labels --> loss='categorical_crossentropy'
    '''

    #MODEL VGG (the old model)
    pad1_1 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1), trainable=False, input_shape=(4096, 1, 1), name='in_train')(img)
    conv1_1 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_1', trainable=False)(pad1_1)
    pad1_2 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1), trainable=False)(conv1_1)
    conv1_2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv1_2', trainable=False)(pad1_2)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), trainable=False)(conv1_2)

    pad2_1 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(pool1)
    conv2_1 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_1', trainable=False)(pad2_1)
    pad2_2 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(conv2_1)
    conv2_2 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv2_2', trainable=False)(pad2_2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), trainable=False)(conv2_2)

    pad3_1 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(pool2)
    conv3_1 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_1', trainable=False)(pad3_1)
    pad3_2 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(conv3_1)
    conv3_2 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_2', trainable=False)(pad3_2)
    pad3_3 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(conv3_2)
    conv3_3 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv3_3', trainable=False)(pad3_3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), trainable=False)(conv3_3)

    pad4_1 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(pool3)
    conv4_1 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_1', trainable=False)(pad4_1)
    pad4_2 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(conv4_1)
    conv4_2 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_2', trainable=False)(pad4_2)
    pad4_3 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(conv4_2)
    conv4_3 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv4_3', trainable=False)(pad4_3)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2) , trainable=False)(conv4_3)

    pad5_1 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1) , trainable=False)(pool4)
    conv5_1 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_1', trainable=False)(pad5_1)
    pad5_2 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(conv5_1)
    conv5_2 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_2', trainable=False)(pad5_2)
    pad5_3 = ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), trainable=False)(conv5_2)
    conv5_3 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', name='conv5_3', trainable=False)(pad5_3)
    pool5 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), trainable=False)(conv5_3)

    fc6 = Convolution2D(4096, 7, 7, activation='relu', name='fc6', trainable=False)(pool5)
    fc6_drop = Dropout(0.5)(fc6)

    #We TRAIN this layer
    fc7 = Convolution2D(4096, 1, 1, activation='relu', name='fc7', trainable=False)(fc6_drop)
    fc7_drop = Dropout(0.5)(fc7)
    fc8 = Convolution2D(2622, 1, 1, name='fc8', trainable=False)(fc7_drop)
    flat = Flatten()(fc8)
    out = Activation('softmax')(flat)
    model = Model(input=img, output=out)

    #We load the weight of the old model so when we construct ours we dont have to retrain all of it.
    if weights_path:
        model.load_weights(weights_path)

    # We construct our new model: first 14 layers of the old + two new ones. The new FC has to be trained and the Softmax layer too.
    fc7_n = Convolution2D(4096, 1, 1, activation='relu', name='fc7_n', trainable=True,  input_shape=train_data.shape[1:])(fc6_drop)
    fc7_drop_n = Dropout(0.5)(fc7_n)
    fc8_n = Convolution2D(8, 1, 1, name='fc8_n', trainable=False)(fc7_drop_n)
    flat_n = Flatten(name='flat_n')(fc8_n)
    out_n = Activation('softmax')(flat_n)
    model2 = Model(input=img, output=out_n)
    #model2.summary()


    sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model2.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    '''train_labels --> loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
       labels --> loss='categorical_crossentropy'
    '''

    model2.fit(train_data,label, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, batch_size=64)
    print('Model Trained')

    #We save the weights so we can load them in our model
    model2.save_weights(pesos_entrenados)  # always save your weights after training or during training

    #We have two options: 1) Return the model here or in the vgg_trained_model Function
    return model2



if __name__ == "__main__":
    im = Image.open('A.J._Buckley.jpg')
    im = im.resize((224, 224))
    im = np.array(im).astype(np.float32)
    im = im.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)

    # For the training stage
    img_width, img_height = 224, 224
    img = Input(shape=(3, img_height, img_width))
    train_data_dir = 'merge/train'
    pesos_entrenados='Modelo_Reentrenado.h5'
    # validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
    nb_train_samples = 1576  # 197 per class and we have 8 classes (8 emotions)
    nb_validation_samples = 0
    nb_epoch = 20


    # Stages to construct the model
    bottleneck()   #Reduce the computational cost
    model=entrenamos_modelo('vggface_weights_tensorflow.h5')  #Construction of the model

    #model.summary()

    out = model.predict(im)
    print(out[0][0])
```

The 'vggface_weights_tensorflow.h5' are a conversion from the model weights in theano to tensorflow. I have used the following script to convert the weights:

```py
model = Model(input=img, output=out)
weights_path = 'vgg-face-keras.h5'
model.load_weights(weights_path)
ops = []

for layer in model.layers:
   if layer.__class__.__name__ in ['Convolution1D', 'Convolution2D', 'Convolution3D', 'AtrousConvolution2D']:
      original_w = K.get_value(layer.W)
      converted_w = convert_kernel(original_w)
      ops.append(tf.assign(layer.W, converted_w).op)
K.get_session().run(ops)
model.save_weights('vggface_weights_tensorflow.h5')
```

The original scripts are from here:

https://gist.github.com/EncodeTS/6bbe8cb8bebad7a672f0d872561782d9

If anyone knows how to solve the problem I will always be grateful.

Comment: If i comment the fit line there's no error..so i've assumed that the error is there.

I am using Keras(1.1.1) + Theano (0.9.0.dev4) + Tensorflow(0.10.0rc0)

Comment: The model's input is `img` which has the size `(None, 3, 224, 224)`, but you try to fit it with `train_data` of size `(1576, 4096, 1, 1)`.

Comment: do you know what//where I have to change in the code? i'm really new in keras :(
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you resized all your images so they are 224 by 224?

The error looks like the model expects a list of images of any size, with 3 channels (RGB), 224 wide and 224 height. It looks more like its the input of your data rather than anything with Keras/the code. Try making sure your directory and data are set up as the model expects?